# Insert into select statament in Pentaho

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I'm currently working on Pentaho and I need to create this "Insert into select" statement from table1 into table2. I simplified the script on the image attached to make it easier to understand (Just one column field), I have the script in a "Execute SQL Script", the script works fine from MYSQL Workbench, but on Pentaho, it doesn't work. I've been reading and I set the table names with its proper syntax (Maybe there's an error there?) anyway I would really appreciate your help.

Thanks in Advance

Diego

[image: img_pentaho]

Comment: Note that using user/dynamic variables for the table names in your script is considered a security risk anywhere or however you run your code.

Comment: Hello! I was just reading that, would you advise me to use a table output? Because if so, there's an issue there: the data from table 1 is obtained from a CSV, and in table 1 there are also columns which are not obtained from the CSV in the first place, and those columns created from table1 need to be insert into table2 alongside the CSV columns as well. Im sorry it sounds I bit confusing, its my first time working with Pentaho.

Comment: Maybe Pentaho is intended for use this way, but certainly what you are doing on MySQL or any other major database would not be recommended.